# I get an error when i Run my flutter vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I was doing my project I had an error when I tried to run my code on the emulator. I can't see any issues when it comes to the code, I think it is something connected with android studio and flutter. I have tried almost everything and I can't solve itThis is what I get when I try to run the code:

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Piotrek\development\sdks\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I would very appreciate if anyone could help me with my problem, it makes my very irritated:)

Answer (score 0):

- clean project by using "flutter clean" command
- then "pub get"
- then run your application

if still same issue ,
you maybe using some of not "**Null safety**" Package

Comment: Hello ahmad, when I clean my project i get this: Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

Comment: i think your path is not valid , please try run above commit inside visual code terminal or android studio terminal

Comment: Could you explain it more detailed please? I am really confused rn. I just want to clarify Im coding w my friend on git

Comment: please see this video that explain how to open terminal of visual studio code , and after 
 open terminal run above command , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeZrd_9qh0c

Comment: I know how to open the terminal. What should I type in there?

Comment: "flutter clean" and then  "pub get" and then run your application (sequences)

Comment: but when I type "flutter clean" in the vs terminal i get this error:                              
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user